# Vertically aligning a tikz drawing with a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I have a graph and a matrix that I would like to display in one line, as in the example below. How can I get the drawing and the matrix to align vertically? The current output makes something that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like the bottom of the matrix to align with the bottom of the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}
\[
 \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, fill=black,inner sep=1pt]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.3cm,baseline=(4.base)]
  \node (1) [label=1] {};
  \node (2) [right of=1,label=2] {};
  \node (3) [below of=1,label=below:3] {};
  \node (4) [right of=3,label=below:4] {};
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node[left] {} (2)
        edge node[left] {} (2)
        edge node[left] {} (3)
        edge node[left] {} (4)
    (2) edge node[left] {} (3)
        edge node[left] {} (4)
    (3) edge node[left] {} (1)
    (4) edge node[left] {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apply a `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` to the `tikzpicture`, since I know that `bmatrix` is already centered on the math axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\[
 \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, fill=black,inner sep=1pt]
 \vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.3cm,baseline=(4.base)]
  \node (1) [label=1] {};
  \node (2) [right of=1,label=2] {};
  \node (3) [below of=1,label=below:3] {};
  \node (4) [right of=3,label=below:4] {};
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node[left] {} (2)
        edge node[left] {} (2)
        edge node[left] {} (3)
        edge node[left] {} (4)
    (2) edge node[left] {} (3)
        edge node[left] {} (4)
    (3) edge node[left] {} (1)
    (4) edge node[left] {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]